# Conditional Rank

Tags: sql, oracle, analytics, rank

So my concern is as follows:
 
If I get a "match" in column 2 I need ranking else null Partition by Column 1 is this possible? So in below example rank is `1,2,3` since in Column 1 it has same column 1 (1003) for 1004 it has no match so I will be getting a null value

**Expected output:**

```
 Column 1 |  Column 2 | Rank
-----------------------------
   1003   |  Match    |   1
   1003   |  Sorias   |   2
   1003   |  Pythn    |   3
   1004   |  Sorias   | null
   1004   |  Pythn    | null
   1004   |  Pythn    | null
```

Comment: Do a simple ROW_NUMBER OVER PARTITION in an inner query and in the outer you check if there is a Match in the respective id and if negative replace ROW_NUMBER  with NULLs

Comment: how do I  write outer query pleae explain

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b8112/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Column1, Column2 ) AS
          SELECT 1003, 'Match'  FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1003, 'Sorias' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1003, 'Pythn'  FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1004, 'Sorias' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1004, 'Pythn'  FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1004, 'Pythn'  FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT Column1,
       Column2,
       CASE WHEN COUNT( CASE WHEN Column2 = 'Match' THEN 1 END ) OVER ( PARTITION BY Column1 ) > 0
            THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Column1 ORDER BY Column2 )
            END AS Rank
FROM   table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b8112/1/0)**:

```
| COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 |   RANK |
|---------|---------|--------|
|    1003 |   Match |      1 |
|    1003 |   Pythn |      2 |
|    1003 |  Sorias |      3 |
|    1004 |   Pythn | (null) |
|    1004 |   Pythn | (null) |
|    1004 |  Sorias | (null) |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sum and row number in window functions. Here is a query which gives you the desired output.

```
 select x.*, case when sum(match) over (partition by column1) >= 1 then rnk else null end final_rank
   from (select column1, column2, row_number() over (partition by column1 order by column2) rnk, 
           (case when column2 = 'Match' then 1 else 0 end) match
      from table a) x
```